# Cannot disable an elements within dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Creating a dynamic div and trying to make the nodes non editable :

```
var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv'); 

var numi = document.myForm.inputboxlength; 

var num = parseInt(numi.value) +1; 
//alert(num); 
numi.value = num; 

var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 

var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div'; 

newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName); 
newdiv.className='divclass';


newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type=\"textarea\" style=\"width:350px; height:44px;\" name=\"txtArea"+num +"\" /> <br> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"removeInputBox(\'"+divIdName+"\')\" value='Remove'/> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"done(\'"+divIdName+"\')\" value='Done'/> " +divIdName;

ni.appendChild(newdiv);
```

This is the function called on the button click:

```
function done(divNum) { 


$(".divclass:not(:last-child) :input").attr("disabled",true);


}
```

But the contents are still editable.Tried almost everything out.

**UPDATE:**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4fr79153/3/

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @EnginÜstün updated fiddle link.

Comment: I'm confused - what are you trying to prevent from being edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might be an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/4fr79153/4/

I changed your selector:

`$("#"+divNum).children('input[type="textarea"]')`

instead of

```
$(".divclass:not(:last-child) :input")
```

Comment: Sure! You have to select corresponding div first. `divNum` variable has the div id value. So, `$('#'+divNum)` selects the parent div. Now we want to find a `textarea` within selected div. `$(input[type='textarea'])` selects inputs of type of textarea. Checkout http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ to find out more about attribute selectors.

Comment: Ok suppose if I have to change something related to `Button` , can I use `$(input[value='Remove'])` ?

Comment: It's not a good idea, you may have many buttons that value.
Why not to use css class or data-attributes for your buttons? Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5